# Why is this <int[]> arrayList changing when I update a variable outside of it? How do I fix this issue?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an <int[]> arrayList and added an int[] `variables` into it. When I change the `variables` however, the int[] inside the arrayList gets updated as well. What is the problem here?

```java
import java.util.*;
public class test2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        //adding an int[] to an int[] arrayList
        ArrayList<int[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] variables = {10, 20};  
        arr.add(variables);
        System.out.println(arr.get(0)[0] + " " + arr.get(0)[1]); // prints: 10 20

        // changing the variables
        variables[0] = 0;
        variables[1] = 5;

        // why does arr's int[] change?
        System.out.println(arr.get(0)[0] + " " + arr.get(0)[1]); // prints: 0 5
        
    }
}
```

I can easily create two separate variables for `x = variables[0]` and `y = variables[1]` and add it to the arrayList using `arr.add(new int[] {x, y})`, however this wont be the case for extremely large variables.

Comment: An array, including an array of primitives, is a reference type. The first element of `arr` is a *reference* to `variables`, not a copy of `variables`. By the way, that an array is a reference type is why an `ArrayList<int[]>` is allowed.

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177561/java-list-changed-when-update-another-one ,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855918/why-do-original-variables-change-when-new-variables-are-changed?rq=3

Comment: Essentially, `arr.get(0)` and `variables` are aliases  of each other.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that both `variables` and `arr.get(0)` point to the same `int[]` array object in memory, so changes to that object affect both, as they both reference it (as opposed to storing a copy of the data).

## Step-by-step walkthrough

This line creates a new `int[]` object in memory, and sets the `variables` as a reference to that specific object:

```java
int[] variables = {10, 20}
```

This line adds the same `int[]` object to the array list:

```java
arr.add(variables);
```

The first element of `arr` is a reference to the same object in memory as `variables`.

This changes the `variables` object to be `{0, 5}`:

```java
variables[0] = 0;
variables[1] = 5;
```

Since the first element of `arr` a reference to the same object referenced by `variables` (i.e. it's the same in-memory object and not a copy of that object), the value returned by `arr.get(0)` will be the same object in  as `variables`.  This is why you're seeing the new values.

## Memory diagram

Perhaps a crude text art picture of the memory, step by step, will help demonstrate:

```
Statement                     References to objects in memory

int[] variables = {10, 20};   int[] {10, 20}
                              ↑
                              variables

arr.add(variables);           int[] {10, 20}
                              ↑          ↑
                              variables  arr[0]

variables[0] = 0;             int[] {0, 5}
variables[1] = 5;             ↑          ↑
                              variables  arr[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

> `int[] variables = {10, 20};`

This creates a new object (akin to popping treasure into being out of nothing, then burying it in a vast beach), then assigns a *reference* to it to variable `variables` (`variables` is like a treasure map; 'assign a reference to it' is like wiping the map clean then scribbling a map to the buried treasure on it.

> `variables[0] = 5;`

This is java-ese for: Take treasure map `variables`. Follow it. Dig down. Open the treasure chest. Take out the coin you find in the first segment inside this chest and replace it with '5'.

> `arr.add(variables);`

This adds **the reference** (the treasure map), **not the object** (not the treasure!) to `arr`.

### But I want to put the treasure in arr!

This is not possible. Java does not work that way. Other than primitives, *everything is a reference*.

### How do I fix it?

Count the `new` (and `int[] v = {10, 20};` is syntax sugar for `int[] v = new int[] {10, 20}`. That's how many objects you have.

If you want an arraylist containing 10 separate int arrays, you need 2 separate `new`. Or all you have is folder of treasure maps, each map leading to the same treasure.

arrays implement `clone()`, if you want that:

```
int[] data = {10, 20};
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) list.add(data.clone());
list.get(0)[0] = 50;
System.out.println(list.get(1)[0]); // prints 10.
```

Remove the `clone()` and that would have printed 50.

### That treasure thing is an abstraction, right?

Not really - the simile works perfectly to understand references, heap, objects, and so forth. `.` and `[]` are dereferencing - they involve walking over to X marks the spot and digging. `=`, `==` aren't. They are about the map themselves. Thus:

```
void foo(int x) {
  x = 5;
}
```

Would not modify the caller's variables at all, i.e. if someone called that with:

```
int y = 10;
foo(y);
System.out.println(y);
```

That would still print 10. However:

```
void foo(AtomicInteger x) {
  x.set(10);
}

AtomicInteger z = new AtomicInteger(5);
foo(z);
System.out.println(z);
```

Would print 10, not 5. Because `.` dereferences (`.set(10)` means: Go to the X, dig, open the box, shout `set(10)` at it. What does that do? Well, the definition of AtomicInteger will know what to do with that shout - whereas `z = whatever;` wipes out your map and scribbles new things on it. It doesn't dig up any boxes.

Any treasure that no maps can ever get to are garbage. The garbage collector will eventually dig em up and toss em out.

Note that lots of 'treasure' (instances of classes, i.e. objects) are 'immutable' - nothing you can do to them directly changes them. For example, `java.lang.String` instances. There is no `.set` method on strings. `toLowerCase()` does not change the string; it crafts a new one and returns it. Such kinds of treasure are convenient, in that you can spread treasure maps to em far and wide without worrying that anybody is going to dig up your treasure and mess with it. However, arrays aren't like that - they can be changed by anybody that has a reference to one.